# "Picking Cards" challenge

Tags: java, ruby, programming-challenge

I recently tried my hand at CodeSprint2 through Interview Street.  Having not coded in quite some time, I wasn't surprised that I had difficulty writing optimized code, but on one problem in particular I can't find where I've gone wrong.  I've compared my code to successful algorithms used by other programmers, and I don't see much difference.  I tried in both Java and Ruby and hit a wall at the 4th test case with both (I'm just learning Ruby so thought it would be a fun exercise to try it - I tweaked my algorithm a little in the process).

The problem is Picking Cards and the description is [here](http://cs2.interviewstreet.com/recruit/challenges/solve/view/4f0a70674f380/4effeea14e3a7).

**Code in Java:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class Cards3 {

    public Cards3()
    {
    }

     public void run()
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> cards = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        try{
            /*
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String input = reader.readLine();

            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(input);
            int T = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
            */

            DataInputStream reader = new DataInputStream(System.in);
            int T = reader.readInt();
            reader.readChar();
            System.out.println("T = " + T);
            //read in and test each subsequence
            for(int i = 0; i<T; i++)
            {
                /*
                input = reader.readLine();
                tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(input);
                int N = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());

                //read in and store cards
                String nextLine = reader.readLine();
                tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(nextLine);
                */

                int N = reader.readInt();
                reader.readChar();

                for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
                {
                    int next = reader.readInt();//Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
                    reader.readChar();
                    cards.add(next);
                }
                Collections.sort(cards);
                System.out.println(numWays(cards) % 1000000007);
                cards = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            }

            reader.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Can not read input.");
        }
    }

    //computers the number of ways to pick up cards in currCards given that
    //numPicked cards have already been picked up
    public long numWays(ArrayList<Integer> cardsLeft)
    {
        int numPicked = 0;
        long numWays = 1;

        //calculate until all cards are picked up
        while(cardsLeft.size() >= 1)
        {
            //if we can't pick up the next card, we're at a dead end - no solutions
            if(cardsLeft.get(0) > numPicked)
                return 0;

            int numCanPick = 0;

            for(int i: cardsLeft)
            {   
                if(i <= numPicked)
                {
                    numCanPick++;

                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            cardsLeft.remove(0);
            numWays *= numCanPick;
            numWays = numWays % 1000000007;
            numPicked++;
        }

        return numWays;
    }

     public static void main(String args[])
       {
            Cards3 d = new Cards3();
            d.run();
       }
}
```

**Code in Ruby**

```
def runProgram
  answers = []
  t = STDIN.gets.to_i
  t.times{ 
    n = STDIN.gets
    numWays = 1
    cards = STDIN.gets.split.map(&:to_i)
    numPicked = 0
    for i in 0...cards.length
      numCanPick = cards.count{|a| a<= i}
      numWays = numWays * (numCanPick-i)
      break if numCanPick==0
      numWays = numWays % 1000000007
    end
     answers << numWays
  }

  puts answers
end

if __FILE__ == $0
 runProgram
 end
```

Comment: I was not able to find a "Picking Cards" problem from the link you provided. The closest I found was the 2011 challenge called "Card Shuffling".

Comment: Try this oneL http://cs2.interviewstreet.com/recruit/challenges/dashboard/

From there you should be able to click on Picking Cards.  

Or, here's a reprint of the problem from a blogger: http://www.programminglogic.com/codesprint-2-problem-picking-cards/

Answer (score 3):

The immediate thing that jumps out to me is your use of an ArrayList for this. By continuously removing the first element, you force the array list to shift everything left one space each time (an O(n) operation assuming no underlying optimizations!)

Instead of removing from the array list (incurring an expensive shift), I would recommend that you keep an index.

```
    while(cardsLeft.size() >= 1)
    {
        //if we can't pick up the next card, we're at a dead end - no solutions
        if(cardsLeft.get(0) > numPicked)
            return 0;

        // ...
        for(int i: cardsLeft)
        {   
             // ...
        }

        // ...

        cardsLeft.remove(0);
        // ...
    }
```

becomes

```
    int cardIndex = 0;
    while(cardIndex < cardsLeft.length())
    {
        //if we can't pick up the next card, we're at a dead end - no solutions
        if(cardsLeft.get(cardIndex) > numPicked)
            return 0;
        // ...
        for(int i = cardIndex; i < cardsLeft.length(); ++i)
        {   
             // ...
        }
        // ...

        //cardsLeft.remove(0);
        ++cardIndex
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: I made the change and still hit the time limit after 3 test cases.